# Show convergence of an algorithm within $m$ steps

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

I am trying to show that the following algorithm outputs the solution to the problem $Ax=b$.

Assumptions $A$ is symmetric positive definite of size $n \times n$ with $m$ distinct eigenvalues. The eigenvalues are known but their respective eigenvectors and the number of times each eigenvector is repeated is not known.

then

\begin{align}
\text{for } &i = 0,\dots, m\\
&r_i = b - Ax_i\\
&x_{i+1} = x_i + \frac{1}{\lambda_i}r_i\\
\text{end}
\end{align}

this algorithm should converge in $m$ steps

What I have done so far:

My aim has been to show that $||x-x_m|| = 0$ which in term will show that $x-x_m = 0$, which will complete our proof.

\begin{align}
e_m &= x - x_m\\
    &= x - x_{m-1} + x_m -x_{m-1}\\
    &= e_{n-1} + \frac{1}{\lambda_{n-1}}r_{n-1}\\
    & = e_0 + \sum_{i=1} ^{m-1} \frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}r_{i}
\end{align}

At this point I tried taking the norm but that does not get me anywhere, I think I am missing something. I would appreciate some ideas and guidance.

Comment: I'm assuming that the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_m$, and the the index $i$ in the loop should go from $1$ to $m$ rather than $0$ to $m$. You DO have to say what $v$, $r_i$ and $x_1$ are, or it's tough to make sense of things. Regardless, the algorithm terminates in $m$ steps because the loop has only $m$ iterations. Did you mean something more useful than that? Also: is $A$ an $m \times m$ matrix? If so, and if e-vals are distinct, then every vector $x$ can be written as a linear combination of the associated eigenvectors, which are all orthogonal.

Comment: My previous comment has a short form: You should spend the effort to make your question meaningful, or you should not expect others to spend any effort answering it.

Comment: Convergence to what ??? Your question is horribly incomplete.

Comment: This is a question from this https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf where this is exercise 2 (a), I have worked out the the other parts as (b), (c) etc as they are more numerical while this is an analytical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can express the initial error $e_0$ as a linear combination of eigenvectors $v_j$ corresponding to the eigenvalues $\lambda_j$:
$$
e_0=\sum_{j=1}^mc_jv_j.
$$
It does not matter that the eigenvalues can be repeated. There is always some eigenvector $v_j$ which we can take from the eigenspace of $\lambda_j$ to make the linear combination.

The initial residual $r_0$ is then
$$
r_0=Ae_0=\sum_{j=1}^mc_j\lambda_jv_j.
$$

Now for the error $e_1$, we have
$$
e_1=e_0-\frac{1}{\lambda_1}r_0
=\sum_{j=1}^mc_jv_j-\frac{1}{\lambda_1}\sum_{j=1}^mc_j\lambda_jv_j
=\sum_{j=2}^m c_j\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1}v_j=\sum_{j=2}^m\tilde{c}_j v_j.
$$
Note that the component corresponding to $v_1$ disappeared.

In this way, you can show that $e_i$ has no component in the eigenspaces corresponding to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_i$ and hence $e_m$ is zero.

Comment: Side note to OP: "There is always some eigenvector..." is the (first) place in this computation where the symmetry of $A$ is used. Are there any others? Where does positive definiteness come in?